# Is there a data annotation equivalent to Entity Framework's fluent API's WillCascadeOnDelete()?

Tags: entity-framework

In my `OnModelCreating` method, I've removed the `CascadeDeleteConventions`, but I'd like to specify a few relationships in my model as having cascading deletes.

However, the relations are defined using attributes (eg `[ForeignKey("Foo")]`), not via the fluent API. Is there an attribute equivalent to the fluent API's `WillCascadeOnDelete` function?

Comment: No. (Sorry, cannot write this as answer because answer requires at least 30 characters; also with that answer I am suspected not being human and I am forced into heavy captcha check to prove not being a bot.)

Comment: I suppose that's what I get for asking a yes/no question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to fool you. I really don't know what to say more, obviously I don't need to explain you how use Fluent API as alternative. Mapping options with data annotations are just a subset of the mapping options with Fluent API and cascading delete is not part of this subset. Maybe you could ask if it's possible to create custom annotations for EF. I never heard of it, but who knows... (btw, the part in parentheses happened indeed when I tried to write "No." as an answer.)